# custom application form as write mode for normal users in service now

Tags: servicenow, service-not-available

In serviceNow, how to change custom application form as write mode for normal users after i used extended my table from task table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you're asking.

I don't want to be presumptuous, but it sounds like you're asking about how to change the security on your table so certain users can access it and write to it.

If I'm right, you need to right-click on your form's header, go to **Configure->Security Rules**, then create ACLs to allow the right users to write to your form. Information on ACLs can be found on the servicenow docs site.